# Поднять 100 ipv6 прокси

Tags: proxy, ipv6

Необходимо поднять 100 ipv6 прокси на сервере, когда-то поднимал ipv4, знаю как это делается, но с ipv6 возникли проблемы.

У меня есть ipv4 сервер: 185.118.66.73
По запросу хостера, тот мне выделил подсеть:
Вам предоставлена **подсеть**: 2a07:14c0:0:8004::/64

А также **шлюз**: Шлюз для указанной подсети 2a07:14c0:0:8004::1/64

Что мне дальше делать с этими данными, был опыт поднятия ipv4 на 3proxy, но с ipv6 я немного профан. Помогите, пожалуйста